# Full calendar v3 Specific event disable dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to do if the event of reservations changes color and you can't drag it, I looked in Google for nothing, I decided to write to Stack support. Stuck on this task thanks for any help and support. Im use (v3 full calendar)

Color changes its okey, but can dragging,

```
                // Event render
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    if (event.status == 'reserved') {
                       // Here im try disable dragging
                        event.editable = false;
                        element.css({
                            'background': 'lemonchiffon',
                        });
                    }else if(event.status == 'available'){
                        element.css({
                            'background': 'lightgreen',
                        });
                    }

                    if(event.gap_beetween_slot === '0'){
                        $(element).find('.fc-resizer').remove();
                    }
                    $(element).find('.fc-title').html(event.title);

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to have realised already, if you set an event's `editable` property to `false`, it will prevent it from being dragged.

Documentation:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object
- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/editable

However the problem is that you're setting the field during the `eventRender` callback. At that moment it's too late, because fullCalendar has already created the HTML of the event from the event's properties. It does not read from them any more after this point. `eventRender` is simply your chance to make further changes to the HTML. Any changes you make to the event's properties are ignored.

Therefore you need to make this change earlier in the process. I think you probably have a couple of options:

1. If you're generating these events in your server-side code (e.g. from a list in a  database, perhaps) then you could set the `editable` property before you transform the data to JSON and return it to fullCalendar.
2. If that isn't possible for any reason, then fullCalendar offers the `eventDataTransform` callback which allows you to modify an event's properties *before* it is rendered to HTML. For example:

```
eventDataTransform: function(event) {
  if (event.status == 'reserved') {
    event.editable = false;
  }
  return event;
}
```

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventDataTransform

Comment: Thank you, its work! Thank you for your help and for the time you took.